# Improving performance of query using Like operator

Tags: java, mysql, query-optimization, sql-like

I'm using a search query to lookup a skus in my DB and I'm having a bad performance return from TrueSight report.

Not sure if there a way I could do for better performance.

my query is:

```
public SkuQuery(final DataSource ds) {
    super(ds, "SELECT sku, description1, buyer, analyst FROM descrip WHERE item_status != 3 AND sku like ? ");
    declareParameter(new SqlParameter(Types.VARCHAR));
    compile();
}
```

Because of the sku like statement, it does a full tables can of 420,000 rows each time it runs. If you rewrite this to do an exact search on sku, which is the primary key, it runs in .016 seconds.

The pattern I'm using is  "sku like '%5052024%';"

Comment: So do you have the complete SKU, or only part of it?

Comment: You _could_ try to create an index on `item_status` to speed the query up but it might be a really bad idea if you have very few distinct values for `item_status`

Comment: It shouldn't have the full SKU necessarily, If I  receive an input string of 4 to 8 characters we run the like query

Comment: You can check if the performance degrade is because of LIKE operator, if yes, try to remove it from the query and use the java code for the same if the performance differs.

Comment: What is the actual parameter value for the query?  Is it `123456%`? Or something more like '123%456%'?

Comment: It is "sku like '%5052024%';"

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava has your best option--do the filtering in Java. It will be much faster

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava can you give an example of the code? is the filter based on the sku or item_status?

Comment: Is it reasonable to expect the user to enter from the beginning of the sku?  Can you remove that leading `%` so it becomes `5052024%`?

Comment: @Andrew S, that might be a thing , I should try it

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear from your question if you could use `=` instead of `LIKE`. Are users not required to enter the whole SKU number?

There is no way to improve the performance of `LIKE` when you have a wildcard at the start of your pattern.

For example, if I ask you to read the telephone book and find all people whose name contains the characters "land" anywhere in their name — beginning, middle, or end — you can't take advantage of the fact that the telephone book is sorted by name. You will have to read the whole book carefully to find the names matching the pattern.

That's how wildcards work in `LIKE` conditions. Unless your pattern has no wildcard at the start, it's forced to do a table-scan. It can't use an index.

There are FULLTEXT indexes in MySQL that allows you to match words within one or more string columns. But it only matches whole words, it can't match patterns that are parts of words.

You might like my presentation [Full Text Search Throwdown](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql) in which I compared several different fulltext indexing solutions.

Comment: It is possible to handle "%123" by creating index on `reverse(sku)` and doing `like reverse(sku) like '321%'` but it won't help with '%123%'

Comment: @user158037, yes, in MySQL you can create a generated column based on an expression, and then index the generated column. But you can't create an index on an expression without adding a column.

Answer (score 0):

Use the query like

```
super(ds, "SELECT sku, description1, buyer, analyst FROM descrip WHERE item_status != 3");
```

In the java code, after getting the data in the `sku`, loop over it checking like

```
while([RESULT_SET-CONDITION]){
    if(sku.contains(5052024)){
        //Your Code
    }
}
```

Although this way will increase the data in the main memory as you are loading more data there.

Comment: That is likely to be much slower -- it requires transferring lots of data from the database to the application.